# Adding a type hint to a Clojure gen-class state access

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

I am writing a Clojure class using `gen-class`. I have a "state" field that I am trying to access in the following code:

```
(ns com.example.sparetime.DateButton
  (:gen-class
    :extends javax.swing.JToggleButton
    :init initialize
    :state state
    :constructors {[Integer] [String]})
  (:import
    [java.awt Insets]))

(if *compile-files*
  (set! *warn-on-reflection* true))

(def insets (Insets. 1 1 1 1))

(defn -initialize [day-number]
  [[(Integer/toString day-number)] day-number])

(defn get-day-number [this]
  (.state this))

(defn -getInsets [this]
  insets)
```

I get a reflection warning on the line containing `(.state this)`. I tried adding a type hint with `(.state ^DateButton this)`, but then I get a compilation error that the compiler is unable to resolve `DateButton` (chicken and egg? Datebutton does not exist until the compiler finishes compiling this file).

Never mind the wisdom of type hinting this code. How do I do it? Do I need to fully qualify the `DateButton` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your class or fully qualify its name. Then the `^DateButton` hint will work and eliminate the reflection.